# Redirecting parameter data type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have 2 places pointing to the same screen

1.

```
this.router.navigate([this.config.AppTree.App.Module.Details.Path], { state: { data: { id: this.TableId } } });
```

2. 

```
this.router.navigate([this.config.AppTree.App.Module.Details.Path], { state: { data: { id: id } } });
```

In both cases the parameters are numbers. The correct ID value is sent, but somehow the data type of the parameter is not the same

This code works, but it is ugly:

```
let params = history.state.data;

    if (typeof (params.id) == 'object') { this.TableId = parseInt(params.id[0]); }
    else { this.TableId = params.id; }
```

I would like to change the way I send the parameter, or the way I receive the parameter. Why does it add into an array in one of the case? Is there a Parse or something I could do to make it look nicer, and maybe not need the `if`?

UPDATE:

definition:

```
TableId: number;
```

I tried

```
this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('state')
```

proposed by Mark Homer. I have

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

and also added it to the constructor, and either `snapshot` either `paramMap` both ways I get `Property does not exist on type ...` . Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: A ternary replacing the `if`? IDK if there's a way to make Angular not do that

Comment: how are you defining  this.TableId?

Comment: shouldnt you be using this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('state') ?

Comment: Could you please create a minimal reproducible StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0):

**Passing data through router**

```
 this.router.navigate([path], { state: { data:anyData });

 this.router.navigateByUrl(path, {
        state: {data:anyData}
    });
```

**Get data on another side**

```
const state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
```

**to answer your q:**

```
const id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data.id
```

Check console.log in here : [Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmpqyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstart.component.ts)

Comment: tried it, does the same. Console log sometimes it's 5, sometimes it's [5]

Comment: @Dude, are you sure your id and this.tableId are numbers, not an array? you see state and data still the same as object except for your variable you pass in there that changed its type. can you try with the static numbers first? id:1,id:4,id:4.

Comment: you can wrtie your code shorter:  this.TableId = +(params?.id?.[0] || params?.id)